# Does Music.app count plays and skips from other devices synced with the library?

Tags: music, apple-music, android, music.app

I use a MacBook Pro and Music.app on it. I also use my Android with Apple Music downloaded, and have an active Apple Music subscription to sync the two devices. However, in the "Songs" tab of Music.app, there are columns for plays and skips.

**Does Apple Music or Music.app on my MacBook count skips and plays from my phone, and/or vice versa?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Music.app portion, yes. When you sync your phone, it'll merge play counts, skip counts, and last played/skipped data with the information in your music library, for songs you have downloaded to your library.

Note that some versions of the Music app on Monterey don't properly record play and skip information when playing music through the app itself, but they continue to update with the phone's information whenever you sync your phone.